# ODP.NET Trace - What is OpsDscGetTDO

Tags: odp.net

we have a .net 4.5 application that encounters performance problems executing ExecuteNonQuery method sometimes.
We enbaled logging and performance monitoring on all components and found in the Oracle Data Provider Trace File a method call OpsDscGetTDO takes sometimes more than 10 Seconds. (mostly less than 1sec).
 
Is there any documentation available on the Oracle Provider Trace Files and especially the methods that are called there?
Does anyone could give me an explanation on what OpsDscGetTDO is?
 
Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please got through the link on how to ask effective questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The trace is primarily designed for Oracle Support use and so it is not documented. I will see if I can shed light on that method, but in general you should open a support ticket for stuff like this.

Comment: I am not able to get an answer for you about the specifics of "OpsDscGetTDO". What I think you should do is set aside the trace and simply reword your question to something like "ExecuteNonQuery takes 10 seconds to return" and then do the usual legwork of providing the SQL or PL/SQL and all the version numbers of ODP.NET and database that are involved and go from there.

Comment: I'm not certain but the mention of TDO in the name suggests that you might be using Oracle User Defined Types (including VARRAYS and NESTED TABLE). These definitely come with a performance cost and if that is an issue, consider using other types such as associative arrays.